# Red5 - Getting an error when I try to connect to server

Tags: java, flash, red5

I get the following error when I try to establish connection between my flash plugin and my red5 server installation. Please help me.

> [ERROR] [RTMPConnectionExecutor#DTQATXJIXLU78-1]
>   org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler - Exception
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.red5.server.scope.Scope$ConcurrentScopeSet.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
>         at org.red5.server.scope.Scope$ConcurrentScopeSet.hasName(Scope.java:1411)
>   ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:na]
>         at org.red5.server.scope.Scope.hasChildScope(Scope.java:819) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:na]
>         at org.red5.server.scope.ScopeResolver.resolveScope(ScopeResolver.java:99)
>   ~[red5-server.jar:na]
>         at org.red5.server.Context.resolveScope(Context.java:154) ~[red5-server.jar:na]
>         at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onCommand(RTMPHandler.java:323)
>   ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
>         at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPHandler.messageReceived(BaseRTMPHandler.java:105)
>   ~[red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
>         at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:57)
>   [red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
>         at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.ReceivedMessageTask.call(ReceivedMessageTask.java:11)
>   [red5-server-common-1.0.5-RELEASE.jar:1.0.5-RELEASE]
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_75]
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   [na:1.7.0_75]
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_75]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [na:1.7.0_75]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [na:1.7.0_75]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build that you are running was compiled with jdk8 and you are running it on jdk/jre 7. This is an issue with the compatibility mode of the jdk and may only be resolved by updating your java version to 8 or getting an new set of jars which were compiled with jdk 7.